# gnuplot 4.6 errorbars on the fly

Tags: gnuplot

Since stats on datafile containing two columns in gnuplot 4.6 provides mean and sd, I was wondering if I can plot errorbars on the fly instead of creating a third column? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a file `data.dat` with two columns, you could get those error bars with a command like:

```
stats 'data.dat' nooutput
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:(STATS_stddev_y) with errorbars
```

What would this mean, however?  All the points have the same standard deviation, which is the value for the whole data set.

I could provide a more complete answer if you describe your data format/data sets in more detail.

Comment: Thanks andyras. You definitely answered my question. I have weibull fit on data.dat file. So I realize that I need to add errorbars based on my fit function 'f12(x) = (x < 0 ? 0 : a12*(x/lambda12)**(n12-1)*exp(-(x/lambda12)**n12))' with Asymptotic Standard Error in %. How do I use errorbars in this case?

Comment: @kuki, if you have a fit parameter for that function that gives you the error (e.g. `lambda12`), you can use it in the same way as the `STATS` variable: `plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:(lambda12) with errorbars`.